# Ionic Native Http Client - Some UTF8 chars breaking response.data

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using native HTTP client (cordova-plugin-advanced-http) in my Ionic 3 project and I think I have found a problem with UTF8 chars on Android.
I am getting the data back from a POST call and the response is usually a JSON that I can parse with the normal JSON.parse function. Whenever there are some non-ascii chars inside (like à è ò ì ù) the json content is returned incorrectly as follows:

- Actual data in the HTTP response:

  ```
  {"activityResponse":{"activityId":"2113000190","errorCode":"0002","errorDesc":"Guasto già chiuso"}}
  ```
- Response.data from the native POST promise:

  ```
  chiuso"}}
  ```

This problem seems to happen only on Android. The iOS side of the plugin is dealing with these chars just fine.
Unfortunately I have to use the native HTTP client for CORS issues and cannot switch back to the standard Angular HTTP client.

I am also setting the following options before the POST request:

```
this.http.setHeader('*', 'Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
this.http.setHeader('*', 'Accept-Charset', 'UTF-8');
this.http.disableRedirect(true);
this.http.setDataSerializer('utf8');
```

Anyone having a similar issue or ideas on how to solve it?

Thanks

Mat

Comment: Problem solved with an extended Content-Type header in the response ("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8"). It seems like the native Java client is using a default ISO-8559 encoding when nothing else is specified.